# Delphi: Use TsiLang in UniGUI

Tags: delphi

I am using TsiLang in UniGUI program, but i am facing one problem in MessageDlg.

**In UniGUI program, the original code is (but the title and button cannot be translated):**

```
MessageDlg(siLangLinked1.GetTextOrDefault('IDS_5'), mtInformation, [mbOK],
         procedure(Sender: TComponent; Res: Integer)
         begin
          edtExpressDoc.SetFocus;
         end
      );
```

If I use the below code, then message box will not be shown in browser.

```
siLangLinked1.MessageDlg(siLangLinked1.GetTextOrDefault('IDS_5'), mtInformation, [mbOK, mbCancel], 0);
```

I need to translate the Title and button(s), anyone knows how to use siLangLinked1.MessageDlg in UniGUI?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate Delphi resource strings which is quite possible in tsiLang. After all resource strings are translated uniGUI will show correct MessageDlg buttons and titles.